# Wordpress - Include php file with name of category?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, include, categories

I'm trying to include a php file which contains description for each of my categories. So when I'm in category Cat1, I want to see the description of Cat1, when I'm in Cat2, the description for Cat2 and so on.

I tried the following code:

```
<?php 
    include (single_cat_title() . '.php');
?>
```

But it just displays the title of the category. When I tried this:

```
<?php
    $name = "Cat1";
    include ($name . '.php');
?>
```

it works, but if i add *single_cat_title()* instead of the hard coded *"Cat1"* it stops working.

Thank you!

Comment: it's wordpress. functions named `foo()` do OUTPUT, `get_foo()` will RETURN that data instead. you're doing direct output with your `single_cat_title()`.

Comment: Ah it makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`<?php 
    include (single_cat_title('',false) . '.php');
?>`

Referenced from: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/#parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php 
    include (single_cat_title("", false) . '.php');
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
    include (get_query_var('category_name') . '.php');
?>
```